# how to solve problem on checkout page after upgrading magento 1x to magento 2x

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, checkout, database, upgrade

[image]

```
Next Exception: Report ID: webapi-5942548a83c3a; Message: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1103 Incorrect table name '', query was: INSERT INTO `` () VALUES () in /opt/lampp/htdocs/texas/texas_newm2/vendor/magento/framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:195
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step1:-** Create file in your magento root

and put this code into that

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$obj->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State')->setAreaCode('frontend'); // for remove Area code is not set error
$storeManager = $obj->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
echo $baseUrl=$storeManager->getStore()->getId();
```

by running this file you got your store id.

**Step 2**:- Go to your database in PHPMyAdmin and search for sales_sequence_meta table then check store_id field that contains your storeid or not and if not then set your store id by editing.

Comment: Step 2:- Go to your database in PHPMyAdmin and search for sales_sequence_meta table then check store_id field that contains your storeid or not and if not then set your store id by editing.    HELPS , THANKS!